# How to disable ICMPv6 messages?

Tags: networking, benchmarks

I am trying to setup a benchmark test on a local network.

I would like to know how I can disable the 'ICMPv6 Router Solicitation' and 'ICMPv6 Multicast Listener Report Message v2' packets that my hosts are sending to each other on my network, since this would harm the performance test.